# SQL query duration as consecutive timestamps difference, grouped by day

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, timestamp

Basically, I have a table like this

| id | timestamp | state | minutes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7/12/2021, 17:38 | off | 14.54 |
| 1 | 7/12/2021, 17:53 | running | 8.39 |
| 1 | 7/12/2021, 18:01 | off | 8.12 |
| 1 | 9/12/2021, 00:04 | running | **big value here** |

The table is ordered by id and then by timestamp ascending. Each id represents a machine and in the first row, for example, the machine was *off* for 14.54 minutes, from 7/12/2021 17:38 till 7/12/2021 17:53 (2nd row). At 17:53 the machine started *running* for 8.39 minutes until 7/12/2021 18:01 etc...

**What I do then is sum all the minutes and group those by day and state**, so I know how much time each machine spent turned off and running, for each day. The problem is that, when the consecutive timestamps are from different consecutive days, I get a wrong sum value for that day. In the example of the table above, I would get that the sum of total minutes in the *off* state would be 14.54+ 8.39 + 8.12 + *big value here*.

Ideally what should happen is a group similar to this (considering only for the off state)

| id | day | state | minutes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7/12/2021 | off | 22.66 |
| 1 | 8/12/2021 | off | 1440 |
| 1 | 9/12/2021 | off | 4 |

I was thinking maybe could artificially add timestamps on the result table like "17/12/2021 24:00" so I always get the intervals cut correctly, for each day, when grouping.

Can you please help me? It is really important!! Thanks

Comment: You can use `least()` to get the lower value of the end of the day or the end of a state.

Comment: you should try introducing a calendar table to cover the days (dates) you are interested in, and then join to this table with overlap conditions. This will repeat the rows spanning across day boundaries. Then for each row in the join you need to find the overlapping timespan, and aggregate/group by the calendar's date

Comment: You describe the `minutes` column as the time spent in that state _after_ the row's `timestamp`, but unless there are missing rows, that would mean `minutes` in row three should be the large number.  The way you are summing looks like you swapped from that column meaning time after to time _before_ the timestamp.  So which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
with Cal as (
  select cast(DayStarts as date) as Date, DayStarts, DayStarts + interval '1 day' - interval '1 second' as DayEnds
  from (
        select  CAST('2021-12-07' AS timestamp(0)) + (n || ' day')::INTERVAL as DayStarts
        from generate_series(0, 10) n
       ) Cal1
),
MyTbl as (
  select 
      Tbl.id
    , tbl.timestamp as StartTS
    , tbl.state
    , timestamp + (tbl.minutes * interval '1 minute') as EndTS 
  from Tbl
)  
select 
    C.Date
  , T.State
  , sum(extract(Epoch from (least(C.DayEnds, T.EndTS)
                             -
                            greatest(C.DaySTarts, T.StartTS)+ interval '1 second'))/60) as minutes
from Cal C
    inner join
    MyTbl T
    on C.DayEnds>=T.StartTS
    and C.DaySTarts<=T.EndTS
group by C.Date, T.State
order by C.Date, T.State
```

Cal is the calendar, produced for the next 10 days starting from 2021-12-07, it returns a date column, and the first/last moments (timestamps) of the date.
Tbl is your table, MyTbl is that one plus an end timestamp (EndTs) by adding the minutes to the timestamp column.
We then join these tables looking for 'overlaps'; then for each overlap, we calculate the minutes of the overlap, and then aggregate by date and state.

The last second of each day is not correctly included, but if rounded to minutes it would be fine. It shouldn't be difficult to change it to use < NextDate, to make it perfectly accurate.

Comment: Worked out perfectly! Thanks a lot.